# Delphi Berlin Unicode Issue

Tags: delphi, unicode, utf-8, delphi-10.1-berlin, byte-order-mark

I have a very strange Delphi compiler issue relating to Unicode characters.

I have a unit with this const definition:

```
const SLANG_SPANISH_ESP = 'Español';
```

When I compile this on my PC, the `ñ` gets converted to the ASCII equivalent. I've used a hex viewer to examine the relevant files:

Within the pas source file, the `ñ` is encoded in UTF-8 as `C3 B1`.

Within the generated DCU file, the `ñ` is encoded in ASCII (?) as `F1`.

All the other Delphi PCs within our group compile the DCU differently, generating the DCU file with the `ñ` encoded in UTF-8 as `C3 B1`.

This is just one example, but many of the non-ASCII characters suffer the same fate.

I have tried hard over the last couple of days to identify the cause, without success. I have eliminated the project files and source code as we use SVN. I double checked by manually copying the project folder from a colleague's PC.

I have looked through the Delphi settings for something that might affect this, without success either.

It's very frustrating and worrying to imagine that the same source code on different PCs compiles to different results. My only hope now is that someone from the community will be able to give me a clue.

Comment: To be clear, the file format is UTF-8

Comment: Try using using a typed constant: const SLANG_SPANISH_ESP : String = 'Español';

Comment: ASCII goes from 00 to 7F. F1 is not an ASCII character, but it does happen to be `ñ` in the common [Latin 1252 ANSI codepage](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-codes.php), so either the source file is converted to ANSI, or the DCU was never compiled from the source after you converted it to UTF-8. Maybe a full build can solve this issue? I happened to have similar issues with "special" characters in Delphi (Seattle) just last weekend, but I decided not to switch to UTF-8 source, and didn't investigate further.

Comment: A full build did not help. The source file is UTF-8 and the ñ is encoded as C3 B1. I have had some success by re-creating the project files from scratch. Now every Delphi produces the same output. It would appear that the original project files were broken in some way. It is unclear what is specifically broken nor why different Delphi's react differently. Still digging...

Comment: When you say "other Delphi PCs", are these with the exact same Delphi release version installed on them or not?

Comment: Yes, the other Delphi PC's all have the same version of Delphi installed.

Comment: The code you present is not the whole story, it will also depend on how you use the constant. Please create a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

I finally got to the bottom of this issue. It turns out that the pas file in question was not saved as UTF-8 despite what the IDE was telling me. In fact this is a known issue/quirk with Delphi where the unit is saved with UTF-8 characters but without the BOM.

You can refer to Marco Cantu's blog on this issue: [The Delphi Compiler and UTF-8 Encoded Source Code Files With no BOM](http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/2018-october-delphi-utf8-no-bom.html)

The reason that the file did not have a BOM was because it was generated using a in-house tool. This tool has since been updated to output the BOM too.

Finally I discovered that, on a given machine, building the project with the IDE or externally via MsBuild.exe would yield different results. The IDE correctly interprets the unit a UTF-8, whereas MsBuild.exe interprets the unit as Ansi.